# Poisson regression, iterative least squares

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution

Imagine, we apply the Poisson Regression Model to the canonical link function:

$\{y_t \mid_{x(t)}, \quad  t = \overline{1, N} \}$ are independent.

$\{y_t \mid_{x(t)} \sim Poisson (\lambda (t)), \quad \ln \lambda(t) = \beta^\top x(t), \quad x(t) \in \textbf{R}^k, t = \overline{1, N} $

How i can write down the parameter $\beta$ calculation with the iterative weighted least squares method algorithm?